# Image and PDF files getting corrupted while uploading on AWS S3

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload images and PDF on AWS S3 using my Spring Boot app. They are getting uploaded in corrupt format without any error. Text files are uploaded successfully.

```
public String uploadDocumentToS3(String bucketName, MultipartFile file) {
    Map<String, String> mimeTypes = new HashMap<String, String>();
    mimeTypes.put("jpeg", "image/jpeg");
    mimeTypes.put("jpg", "image/jpeg");
    mimeTypes.put("png", "image/png");
    mimeTypes.put("pdf", "application/pdf");
    mimeTypes.put("txt", "text/plain");
    String fileExtension =  file.getOriginalFilename().substring(file.getOriginalFilename().lastIndexOf(".")+1);
    LOGGER.info("File Extension " + fileExtension + " MIME " + mimeTypes.get(fileExtension));
    final String s3FileName = LocalDateTime.now() + "_" + file.getOriginalFilename();
    LOGGER.info("Uploading file on S3 with name= " + s3FileName);
    ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
    metadata.setContentType(mimeTypes.get(fileExtension));
    metadata.setContentLength(file.getSize());
    metadata.addUserMetadata("title", "Business Onboarding Doc");
    PutObjectRequest request;
    try {
        request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, s3FileName, file.getInputStream(), metadata);
        amazonS3.putObject(request);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error while uploading S3 file using InputStream " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return s3FileName;
}
```

Below is the dependencies we have used.

```
compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.11.946'
```

Comment: corrupted in what way? Have you inspected the original file and compared it to the uploaded file, on a byte basis that is, are there leading / trailing bytes that do not match, does the uploaded file end too early, Have you tried it with very large text files?

Comment: @luk2302 Uploaded PDF file is of 300KB. On AWS S3 bucket it is of same size. But while opening it on S3 it is displaying file is corrupted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My code works fine. The issue was in the AWS API Gateway. We need to add `'*/*'` in the Binary Media Types to make file uploading work.

For Reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html

Comment: would have never figured it out myself. Thanks