# Corrupted PDF in S3 pre signed URL with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3

**I'm having problems with the pre signed URL of S3**

When I try to download my browser shows a error message saying that the PDF File is corrupted.
However, when I attempt to download by calling directly via the byte stream, it works fine.

*My code:*

```
   public URL getSignedURL(FileS3 filesS3) {
        if (!clienteS3.doesBucketExistV2(bucketName)) {
            System.out.println("O bucket informado não existe [" + bucketName + "].");
            throw new NullPointerException("O bucket informado não existe [" + bucketName + "].");
        }

        java.util.Date expiration = new java.util.Date();
        long expTimeMillis = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
        expTimeMillis += MySettings.AWS_S3_EXPIRATION_TIME;
        expiration.setTime(expTimeMillis);
        //
        // Generate the presigned URL.
        System.out.println("Generating pre-signed URL.");
        GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest
                = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, filesS3.getUrl())
                        .withMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                        .withExpiration(expiration);
        URL url = clienteS3.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
        //
        filesS3.setPreSignedUrl(url);
        //
        return url;
    }
```

**Attempt of solution:**

1. Content Type specify. Result: this S3 error "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method"

Comment: can you please share https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ?

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66067705/image-and-pdf-files-getting-corrupted-while-uploading-on-aws-s3 if it solves your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try providing the `Cotent-Type` of `application/pdf` as a response header within the url using `withResponseHeaders()` method, see if that resolves the mismatch.

Update to the code above:

```java
GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, filesS3.getUrl())
        .withMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
        .withExpiration(expiration)
        .withResponseHeaders(new ResponseHeaderOverrides().withContentType("application/pdf"));
```

Comment: Answer based on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/GeneratePresignedUrlRequest.html